# Customize Slack Notifications banner/alerts?

Tags: notifications, big-sur, slack

Is it possible to customize Slack new message notification banners so **Reply** button is displayed automatically (without having to click 'Options' > 'Reply'). I have searched already within System Preferences > Notifications without luck.

**Note**: Slack Notifications were working this way prior the Big Sur update.

I know this might sound trivial but it's currently driving me crazy. Any help appreciated!